# Rank of value within a subset based on range of another column

Tags: sql, scala, apache-spark, pyspark

I have the following DataFrame (call it `dfTest`):

| item | position | value |
| --- | --- | --- |
| a | 1 | 8 |
| b | 2 | 9 |
| c | 3 | 10 |
| d | 4 | 7 |
| e | 5 | 9 |

What I am trying to do is that, given a distance limit `1`, find out the ranked index (sort by descending manner) of `value` in each row within a subset of rows whose distances (defined by `position` column) to this `item` are not greater than `1`.

For example, the desired output (call it `dfResult`) should be:

| item | position | value | rank |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| a | 1 | 8 | 2 |
| b | 2 | 9 | 2 |
| c | 3 | 10 | 1 |
| d | 4 | 7 | 3 |
| e | 5 | 9 | 1 |

Explanation:

1. For `a` row. Since `b` is the only `item` whose distance to `a` is <= 1 (`abs(2-1)=1`), the sorted subset of `value` is `[9,8]` and `a`'s `value` is 2nd in order, therefore the `rank` of `a` is 2.
2. For `b` row. Here, `a` and `c` are the `item`s with distances to `b` <= 1 , the sorted subset of `value` is `[10,9,8]` and `b`'s `value` is 2nd in order, therefore the `rank` of `b` is 2.
3. For `c` row. Here, `b` and `d` are the `item`s with distances to `c` <= 1 , the sorted subset of `value` is `[10,9,7]` and `c`'s `value` is 1st in order, therefore the `rank` of `c` is 1.
4. ...

Any solution in Spark SQL, Scala or PySpark is appreciated!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You may use a self-join to determine related items across the entire table (eg in the event you had an item `f` with a position of `2` also, `a`'s rank may change) and the `rank` window function to achieve your desired rank.

Examples using spark-sql, pyspark and scala are included below:

#### Using spark-sql

```sql
SELECT
    d.item,
    d.position,
    d.value,
    d.rank
FROM (
    SELECT
        i1.*,
        i2.item as other_item,
        RANK() OVER (
            PARTITION BY i1.item
            ORDER BY i2.value DESC
        ) as rank
    FROM
        dfTest i1
    INNER JOIN
        dfTest i2 ON ABS(i1.position-i2.position)<=1
) d
WHERE item=other_item;
```

[View working demo on db-fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/hxCNBvc9ST6ZF9kTTc5gkG/0)

#### Using pyspark API

```py
from pyspark.sql import functions as F
from pyspark.sql import Window

dfResult = (
    dfTest.alias("i1")
          .join(
              dfTest.alias("i2"),
              F.abs(
                  F.col("i1.position")-F.col("i2.position")
              ) <=1,
              "inner"
          )
          .withColumn(
              "rank",
              F.rank().over(
                  Window.partitionBy("i1.item").orderBy(F.col("i2.value").desc())
              )
          )
          .where(F.col("i1.item")==F.col("i2.item"))
          .select("i1.*","rank")
          
)
```

#### Using scala

```py
val dfResult = 
    dfTest.alias("i1")
          .join(
              dfTest.alias("i2"),
              abs(
                  col("i1.position")-col("i2.position")
              ) <=1,
              "inner"
          )
          .withColumn(
              "rank",
              rank().over(
                  Window.partitionBy("i1.item").orderBy(col("i2.value").desc())
              )
          )
          .where(col("i1.item")==col("i2.item"))
          .select("i1.*","rank")
```

#### Output

```
dfResult.show(truncate=False)
```

```
+----+--------+-----+----+
|item|position|value|rank|
+----+--------+-----+----+
|   a|       1|    8|   2|
|   b|       2|    9|   2|
|   c|       3|   10|   1|
|   d|       4|    7|   3|
|   e|       5|    9|   1|
+----+--------+-----+----+
```

Let me know if this works for you.

Comment: Thanks! This is exactly what I needed. To add a slice of tip, `dfTest` needs to be `cache`ed before self-joining. I'm using Spark 2.4.3 and Scala 2.12.15.